# Handling failed payments and redirecting back to website with Razorpay in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, payment-gateway, razorpay

I'm developing a web application using Java Spring Boot and integrating Razorpay for payments. I have successfully implemented the payment flow, but I'm facing an issue when the payment fails on Razorpay. I want to redirect the user back to my website with a proper error message in such cases.

Here's the relevant code snippet from my Java Spring Boot application:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrrbv.png)

Comment: avoid code's  image use text and provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)